# AWS throttling limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, throttling, aws-iot

I am reading this document:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot

It contains a table of the amounts of requests per second that AWS supports. For example, DescribeThing supports up to 10 operations per second.

My questions are - are these per account or per thing shadow? If this is per account, intending to have millions of things will result in reaching these limits fairly soon, which renders shadow attributes unfit for access as a temporary space, for example, if I need to get it every 5-10 min. Anyone run into the problem ?

Comment: At the top of the page, it indicates that these default limits are per AWS account, per region (unless explicitly indicted otherwise).

Comment: Thanks! I guess the question here then becomes how to go about best practices to design systems without hitting AWS limits, of which seems to be plenty.

Comment: You can typically request quota increases with justification - this helps AWS plan capacity. I'm not sure which IOT limits can be raised, so you'll need to investigate. Quota limits also protect new AWS users (e.g. from accidentally launching 50 x1 instances).